# Django Admin page queryset dynamic filter

Tags: django, django-models

in the following Django Admin page I want the Model query set to be filtered by the Brand_id whenever I choose/change the Brand.

[image]

This is the way that my models are setup:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Year(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default= None, blank = True, null= True)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.year)
```

I tried many attempts and searched for solutions but all of them in vain. My starting point now is to use the get_form function in the following way:

```
class YearAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['year', 'model', 'brand']
    list_filter = ['brand', 'model']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields["model"].queryset = Model.objects.filter(brand_id=2)
        return form
admin.site.register(Year, YearAdmin)
```

instead of having "brand_id=2" I would like to have something like "brand_id = currently_chosen_brand_id" in a dynamic way.

How can this be done?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by accessing the selected `brand_id` and filtering the `Model` queryset accordingly so your code should looks like this:

```
class YearAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['year', 'model', 'brand']
    list_filter = ['brand', 'model']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            brand_id = request.Get.get('brand__id')
            if brand_id:
                form.base_fields["model"].queryset = Model.objects.filter(brand_id=brand_id)
            else:
                form.base_fields["model"].queryset = Model.objects.none() # this returns an empty queryset if no brand is selected
        return form
admin.site.register(Year, YearAdmin)
```

if you want to dynamically update the `Model` queryset based on the selected `brand` in real-time, you should using JavaScript and AJAX. you'll need to override the admin template to add custom JS code that listens to changes in the `brand` field and sends an AJAX request to fetch the corresponding `Model` queryset

your admin.py should looks like this:

```
class YearAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Year
        fields = '__all__'

    class Media:
        js = ('js/year_admin.js',)

class YearAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = YearAdminForm
    list_display = ['year', 'model', 'brand']
    list_filter = ['brand', 'model']

admin.site.register(Year, YearAdmin)
```

create a new HTML file named year_change_form.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/year_admin.css' %}" />{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'admin/year_admin.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

note that `chang_form.html` is one of the django admin's default templates it represents the form used for adding or editing instances of a model in django admin interface.

then create a JavaScript file named `year_admin.js` with this code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#id_brand').change(function () {
            var brandId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/admin/get_models/',
                data: {
                    brand_id: brandId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var modelField = $('#id_model');
                    modelField.empty();
                    $.each(data.models, function (index, value) {
                        modelField.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value.id).text(value.name));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

make sure to update the URL `admin/get_models/` to match your actual URL configuration

you might need `year_admin.css` as well

with these changes the `Model` dropdown should be dynamically updated based on selected `Brand`

your application layout should looks something like this:

```
your_app_name/
             |--admin.py
             |--models.py
             |--templates\      
             |         |
             |         |__admin/        
             |               |
             |               |__your_app_name/
             |                             |
             |                             |__year_change_form.html
             |--static/
             |      |
             |      |__admin/  
             |             |
             |             |__your_app_name/
             |                           |
             |                           |__year_admin.js
             |                           |
             |                           |__year_admin.css
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for your help! However I tried it, and it does not work as I want, and I cannot figure out how to make it work. The "request.Get.get('brand__id')" gets the brand_id only when the page is loaded, but I need it to get the brand_id every time that I choose a brand and uplodate the model queryset accordingly. By any chance do you know what else I could do?

Comment: I have modified the answer, I hope this time it works

Comment: Thanks again Kiarash! I used the codes you gave me with a function in views.py to make it work! I appreciate your help a lot, very kind from you. I will leave the code that I added for anyone else in the future.

def obtain_models(request):
    brand_id = request.GET.get('brand_id')
    
    if brand_id:
        selected_brand = Brand.objects.get(id=brand_id)
        models = Model.objects.filter(brand=selected_brand)
    else:
        models = Model.objects.all()

    data = serializers.serialize("json", models)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)